# c++ including header file in unnamed namespace

Tags: c++

I have a class called Cache used within a toolkit (a file with various publicly accessible methods). Cache is refreshed using a callback, which requires a functor object. The functor object calls one of Cache's functions, refresh() on the instance of Cache in my toolkit.

The instance is within an unnamed namespace in the toolkit (since I don't want clients having direct access to it).

Now, I had this all working, but would really like Cache to have its own header file to make it clear what methods are available on it.

My problem is that I have the following:

```
// toolkit.cxx
#include "cache.h"

// Can't define operator()() here since it needs access the to cache instance
struct Functor {
   void operator() ();
};

// Define Cache's fucntions here (including use of Functor)

namespace {
   Cache cache;

// This gives a compiler error - definition of operator Functor::()() is not in namespace enclosing 'Functor'
   void Functor::operator() () {
      cache.refresh();
   }
}
```

So I can't define `Functor::operator()()` inside the unnamed namespace, and it can't go outside either.

One solution I have considered is to bring the whole lot inside the unnamed namespace, but this would have to include the `#include` as well. Is this recommended? It's not something I have really seen done before (which suggests it may be a bad plan...), and I couldn't find much information on the pros/cons of such an approach.

This would solution would look like:

```
// toolkit.cxx

namespace {
   #include "cache.h"

   Cache cache;

   struct Functor {
     void operator()() {
        cache.refresh();
   };

  // Define Cache's fucntions here (including use of Functor)
}
```

Could anyone comment on the pros/cons (especially cons) of this second approach? Any alternative solutions would also be welcome

Comment: You should be able to implement `void Functor::operator() ()` outside the anonymous `namespace`, using the same code. Does that not work for you?

Comment: ahh yes, I don't know why I was thinking it had to be either before the namespace or inside it - implementing it after the namespace works fine. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to put that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Define `Functor` within the anonymous `namespace`.

```
#include "cache.h"

namespace {

   Cache cache;

   struct Functor {
      void operator() () {
         cache.refresh();
      }
   };
}
```

**Solution 2**

Define `Functor` after the definition of the anonymous `namespace`.

```
#include "cache.h"

namespace {

   Cache cache;

}

struct Functor {
   void operator() () {
      cache.refresh();
   }
};
```

**Solution 3**

Declare `Functor` before the anonymous `namespace` but define
`Functor::operator()` after the definition of the anonymous `namespace`.

```
#include "cache.h"

struct Functor {
   void operator() ();
};

namespace {

   Cache cache;

}

void Functor::operator() () {
   cache.refresh();
}
```